# Configure PyCharm IDE to organize the imports the way Eclipse does (Django development)

Tags: python, django, pycharm, python-import

I am using PyCharm for Django web application development. The tool is great, except that I need to add every import statement manually (i.e. the 'optimize imports' feature doesn't work).

Is there any way to make it work the same way Eclipse does when developing Java applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to type imports manually, there is a relevant documentation page, see:

- [Creating Imports](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/creating-imports.html)

Imagine you've written the following code forgetting to import `os`:

```
print os.getcwd()
```

Then, focus the word `os` and hit `Alt+Enter` combination, you'll get the popup from which you can choose what to import, choose `os` from the list.

Also, there is an ["Import Assistant"](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Auto-import) that fires up tooltips on unresolved imports on the fly.

And, FYI, ["Optimize Imports"](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/optimizing-imports.html) feature works with existing imports and removes unused entries.

Hope this is what you were asking about.